# How do you add symbol, name, and logo to a token?

Tags: metaplex, token, metadata

When creating a token, I want to add symbol, name, and logo to my token so it shows up on wallets and explorers correctly.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add metadata to a spl-token, you need to use the [Metaplex Metadata Fungible Token Standard](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/token-standard#the-fungible-standard).

With JavaScript, you can use the `@metaplex-foundation/js` and `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` libraries to create a metadata account associated with your token.

```
import { DataV2, createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata';
import { findMetadataPda } from '@metaplex-foundation/js';

const metadataPDA = await findMetadataPda(mintKeypair.publicKey); // This is derived from the mint account's public key
const tokenMetadata = {
        name: "Test Token", 
        symbol: "TEST",
        uri: https://token-creator-lac.vercel.app/token_metadata.json,
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
        creators: null,
        collection: null,
        uses: null
      } as DataV2;
const createNewTokenTransaction = new Transaction().add(
        createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction({
            metadata: metadataPDA,
            mint: mintPublicKey,
            mintAuthority: userPublicKey,
            payer: userPublicKey,
            updateAuthority: userPublicKey,
          },
          { createMetadataAccountArgsV2: 
            { 
              data: tokenMetadata, 
              isMutable: true 
            } 
          }
        )
await sendTransaction(createNewTokenTransaction, connection);
```

The above sets the metadata to use the `name` "Test Token", `symbol` "TEST", and the logo to the `image` field in the json from `uri`.

Comment: Even though, I added metadata to my token, all wallets and even Solana Explorer take metadata from the legacy token-list: https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list/blob/main/src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json. I can't update that file because its repo is read-only. So, in fact, I have no way to update my token logo and name. @Jacob Creech, I would appreciate any advice on resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

An important point to note: if your token is fungible, then according to the metaplex metadata standard, it must have a decimals value > 0.  If your token has been set to decimal values 0 it will be displayed on UIs which comply with the metaplex metadata standard as an NFT even if it has supply > 1.  So be sure to set decimals to at least 1 if you want your token to be displayed as a "token".  This means that for all programmatic purposes for which you previously interacted with your mint, you must multiply token count by 10 since the on-chain amount values now represent "decitokens" not whole tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Another method to add token metadata to a SPL token is using websites for it (which basically run the same command as jacob described).

E.g. with https://token-creator-lac.vercel.app/ or https://app.strataprotocol.com/launchpad

Comment: the quality of this answer could be improved by elaborating the contents of the URLs

Comment: i tried this site "https://token-creator-lac.vercel.app/" but i got this error

undefined: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Blockhash not found