# How can I register new spl-token to spl-token list(Naming and Logo)?

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program

I'm going to register my spl-token to Solana spl-token list.
I used to use https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list before.
But today, I saw the message "This repository has been archived by the owner before Nov 8, 2022. It is now read-only."
Could you explain how to register new spl-token now?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to answer here: [How do you add symbol, name, and logo to a token?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/216/how-do-you-add-symbol-name-and-logo-to-a-token/217#217)

Token metadata is added using Metaplex's Token Metadata Program instead of the token-list.

You can read more about it here: https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/overview

You can also use the metaplex SDK to add metadata to a token: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js