# Token registration

Tags: spl-token, token, spl-associated-token-account

I would like to register a token, as currently seeing a warning ⚠️ sign in in the wallet. Also on one of the token scans. And can not find tokens within other wallets. It just doesn't show up by searching with the token address.
Reached out wallet support, they said I have to register it.
Going rounds, and nobody really help.
May I ask someone who know how to do it and advice (Note, I do not code)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I register new spl-token to spl-token list(Naming and Logo)?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5203/how-can-i-register-new-spl-token-to-spl-token-listnaming-and-logo)

Comment: No. Because I created a token on Dexlabs, and to Metadata has been created already. Now the problem is this little warning sign attached to the token in the wallet “Unverified token”, also on the tokenen explorer I see this: “ Warning! Token names and logos are not unique. This token may have spoofed its name and logo to look like another token. Verify the token's mint address to ensure it is correct.”